# Live streaming in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, video-streaming, wifi, live-streaming

I have read a lot of posts about live streaming in iPhone, but none of them really works.

The project I want to work out is as follow:

There is a MUTE movie streaming in a movie theater. I want to get the time code (the position it is playing) through wifi and makes iPhone/iPod Touch to play/stream an audio track at the same time code.

May I ask how to achieve it?

UPDATE: Latency is expected and will be taken into consideration. Small time difference is acceptable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The variable nature of a wireless connection and the latency involved will completely obliterate the video/audio sync you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, I have taken into consideration. Latency will be checked and the time code will be corrected. Small time difference is acceptable in my case.